# Grails unique compound key issues

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given a GORM class:

```
    class PriceSheet {

    Client client
    Population population
    Product product
    RevenueModelType modelType

    BigDecimal price

    static constraints = {
        client(unique: ['population', 'product', 'modelType'])
    }
}
```

I'm wanting a PriceSheet to be saved/updated only if the client, population, product and modelType are unique.  (There should only be one pricesheet item for combination of client, population, product and modelType).

The key is being created in mySQL.

My issue is the grails validation passes, but the save fails.

```
    priceSheetInstance.validate()

    if (priceSheetInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond priceSheetInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    priceSheetInstance.save flush:true
```

Any ideas or suggestions?  I put the debugger on a breakpoint after validate and see errors are empty.

Grails 2.3.10

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell GORM which properties make up your composite primary key and then your domain class needs to implement Serializable. The end result is something like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class PriceSheet implements Serializable {
    Client client
    Population population
    Product product
    RevenueModelType modelType

    BigDecimal price

    static constraints = {        
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['client', 'population', 'product', 'modelType']
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if(!(other instanceof PriceSheet)) return false
        other.client == client && other.population == population && other.product == product && other.modelType == modelType
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()

        builder.with {
            append client
            append population
            append product
            append modelType
        }

        builder.toHashCode()
    }    
}
```

You can read more about GORM composite keys [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#compositePrimaryKeys).

Comment: Thanks for option, but I'd rather not have the primary key be a composite.  According to docs, I should be able to do it as I'm trying with unique validator

Comment: Yes but you have to keep this in mind (straight from the docs): It is possible (though unlikely in practice) for uniqueness validation to pass but for the subsequent save to fail. If another save or update happens to update the database between the Grails check and the actual save of your instance, the call will fail. The only way to prevent this would be to use a transaction at the SERIALIZABLE isolation level, but this is very bad for performance. You might be better off calling save() and then checking for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution was wrapping withNewSession in controller for saves:

```
    PriceSheet.withNewSession {

        priceSheetInstance.validate()

        // needed to call save in order to check the unique compound key
        // validate alone wasn't working
        // also needed to wrap withNewSession above
        // PriceSheet GORM object implements Serializable as well
        // spent way more time than expected on this.... wrestled with Grails

        if (priceSheetInstance.hasErrors() || (priceSheetInstance.save(failOnError: true) && priceSheetInstance.hasErrors())) {
            respond priceSheetInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'priceSheet.label', default: 'Price Sheet'), priceSheetInstance?.id])
                redirect (action: 'index')
            }
            '*' { respond priceSheetInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }
```

I didn't have to wrap withNewSession for updates... in fact, wrapping withNewSession for updates was causing StaleObjectExceptions