# Grails creating constrain for unique object on multiple attribute of Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a Domain Class as First.
which has attributes named objectA of ClassA, a String name and a Joda DateTime object as date.

There must be a unique object of First for every unique combination of  date, objectA and name.

I have given the following definition of teh class and the constraint. This works perfectly fine if I am creating the domain object from grails scaffolding View.I get error if I create a duplicate entry:

```
1 error prohibited this record from being saved
There were problems with the following fields:
Property [name] of class [class in.test.First] with value ["nameValue"] must be unique
```

But the same object gets created multiple times if code is executed from a service or controller.(It's very weird.)

```
class First {

    ObjectId id
    ClassA objectA
    String name
    DateTime date


    static mapping = {
        date index: true
        objectA index: true
        name index: true
    }

    static constraints = {
        name(unique: ['objectA', 'date'])
   }
```

What is the correct way of defining a Domain class with such properties?

PS : No hibernate plugin is used, using mongoDB as only Database.

```
plugins {
    ....
    compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
    ....
}
```

UPDATE: 
Looked this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816736/grails-unique-compound-key-issues/31844007#31844007)

added

```
static mapping = {
    id composite: ['objectA', 'date', 'name']
}
```

But, this does not seems to work.

Comment: You should not be using id as a property name, try renaming as objectId

Comment: Please check the edit @corky_bantam any reason for rename even if my project only has MongoDB as datebase.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816736/grails-unique-compound-key-issues/31844007#31844007

Comment: Checked and tried -> id composite: ['objectA', 'date', 'name'] , but it does not work.